# Headset Microphone not found in Windows 10 Bootcamp

Tags: mac, bootcamp, audio, headphones, microphone

I have a headset microphone that I originally purchased for my PlayStation 4, however, I noticed that the microphone was also able to work on my iMac, and I was very pleased to know that because it is a microphone with good quality and it's easy to use. Anyway, I'm using Bootcamp to use Windows 10 so I can play some games that are unavailable on MacOSX, and I ran into a problem that the only microphone Windows can detect is my iMac microphone and not my headset microphone. I've tried several things to fix this, but I haven't gotten a result I wanted. The microphone only has one jack, that connects to the back of my iMac and the headphones work fine, but like I said the microphone is not being detected. Hopefully, you can help me!

Comment: I take it you followed the Apple Bootcamp instructions that ran the apple driver installer at the end of the setup?  You may need the apple sound driver instead of the default windows one.

Comment: @ThomasNelson So how do I get those?

Comment: Apple used to let you download them but now they are only available if you follow the bootcamp wizard.  This is the last one you can download https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?viewlocale=en_CA&locale=en_CA otherwise you'll have to follow the bootcamp wizard to add the drivers to the boot camp installation.